# How can I call other database's stored procedure in method

Tags: c#, mysql

When I first connect to MySQL, used dbname is **DataBase1** (main DB)

Sometimes, I need to call other stored procedure named 'usp_select_query' which exists in **DataBase2** (sub DB)

DataBase1,2 exist on the same server, same account.

In console, this is executed well.

call DataBase2.use_select_query; in DataBase1  // ok

```
 c# code
 DataSet ds = DbHelper.CallUSP("usp_select_query", para);  // of course error

 DataSet ds = DbHelper.CallUSP("DataBse2.usp_select_query", para);  //  error

 DataSet ds = DbHelper.CallUSP("`DataBse2`.`usp_select_query`", para);  //  error
 
  error Message :Procedure or function '``**DataBase2**`.`usp_select_query``' cannot be found in database '`**DataBase1**`'

public static DataSet CallUSP(string usp, params MySqlParameter[] parameters)
        {
            try
            {
                string query = usp;      
                if(conn.State!= ConnectionState.Open)
                conn.Open();                
                MySqlCommand com= conn.CreateCommand();
                com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                com.CommandText = query;                
                if(parameters!=null)
                    com.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);
                MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(com);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                adapter.Fill(ds);
                conn.Close();
                adapter.Dispose();
                com.Dispose();       
                return ds;       
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                conn.Close();
                LogE(MKSession.COMPANYINDEX,usp,ex.Message);                
            }
            conn.Close();
            return null;
        }
```

How can I do it?

Comment: You need to construct your connection string correctly and specify the database you want to use and pass it to the method, then open that connection. Your code does not show where you set such a requirement.

Comment: I konw that. but i want know, how to easy call other database's procedure, not to make other connection.

Comment: Please include the full error (with stacktrace) in your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using MySQL Connector/NET (aka `MySql.Data`), this is a known bug in the latest version: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=100391

You can work around it by switching to [MySqlConnector](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/) instead, which has a similar API but [fixes this and other bugs](https://mysqlconnector.net/tutorials/migrating-from-connector-net/#fixed-bugs).

Comment: what can i do   to choice your answer?.. sorry BG. T T

Comment: @kimsanghoon Does this article help? https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score -1):

I'm just modify my method.
it is may not efficency.
but It is work for me.

```
 public static DataSet CallUSP(string usp, params MySqlParameter[] parameters)
        {
            try
            {
                //add variable for dbname,usp
                string mdbName = "";
                string oldDbName = conn.Database;
                string[] lines = usp.Split(new string[] { "." }, StringSplitOptions.None);


                //set the value
                if (lines.Length > 1)
                {
                    mdbName = lines[0];
                    usp = lines[1];
                }

                string query = usp;      
                if(conn.State!= ConnectionState.Open)
                conn.Open();

               //change database
               if (mdbName != "")
                    conn.ChangeDatabase(mdbName);


                MySqlCommand com= conn.CreateCommand();
                com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                com.CommandText = usp;
                if(parameters!=null)
                    com.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);
                MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(com);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                adapter.Fill(ds);     
                
                //reset orgin databse 
                if (mdbName != "")
                    conn.ChangeDatabase(oldDbName);
                
                conn.Close();
                adapter.Dispose();
                com.Dispose();
               return ds;       
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                conn.Close();
                LogE(MKSession.COMPANYINDEX,usp,ex.Message);                
            }
            conn.Close();
            return null;
        }
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.